# Gradient options in Android?

Tags: android, layout

I am posting radial code for Gradient layout.. 
what can i use for linear layout ?
Or in simple i need liner gradient layout in my android app background.. without using image ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="#93cc1a" 
            android:endColor="#6C9B06"
            android:type="radial"
            android:gradientRadius="326"
        />                
    </shape>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but does taking out the android:type and android:gradientRadius work?

Comment: yes i am asking for that ..:)

Comment: Refer My Blog, I had gave detailed Explanation there Here is the [Link](http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/2011/03/adding-gradient-effects-to-android.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<gradient android:type="linear" 
 android:startColor="#ffffff" 
 android:endColor="#005aa9" 
 android:angle="270.0" />
```

Are you asking about linear gradient?

Comment: ya . its the code which i need... can you please explain about android:angle

Comment: anlge determs direction of gradient: 0 - vertical from startColor to endColor, 270 - vertical from endColor to startColor; 90 and 180 - horizontal, etc

Comment: You can also set `android:centerColor` if you wanted to, say, go from red to green to blue instead of just red to blue.

Answer (score 0):

> ya . its the code which i need... can you please explain about
>   android:angle

- 0 = left to right (startColor > endColor)
- 90 = bottom to top (startColor > endColor)
- 180 = right to left (startColor > endColor)
- 270 = top to bottom (startColor > endColor)